# How can I sum up the values of two functions?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have two classes. In class B I want to change the values of the variables in class A, which are defined in functions: some and anyt, with the help of the functions in class B: frog and lion.
For example, I multiply by 2 or 3..

I get the Error:

```
 File "E:/Python/Akustik/Akustik/Test.py", line 20
    A.some(a,b,c)  = A.some(a,b,c)* 2
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

I know what does that mean, but i can't dispense with the functions in class A and B, does anybody have a tip?

here is the code:

```
class A:

    def some(self,a, b, c):

        self.a = 4
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3

    def anyt(self, p, g, f):

        self.p = 5
        self.g = 8
        self.f = 1


class B(A):

    def frog(self):

        A.some(a,b,c)  = A.some(a,b,c)* 2


    def lion(self):

        A.anyt(p,g,f)= A.anyt(p,g,f) * 3
```

Comment: Note, `A.some` is an instance method, and you are using it directly off of the class, so even calling them isn't going to work, not to mention, those variables are not defined that you are passing in as arguments...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign the value of an expression to a function call. In your case if you want to change the value of variables a, b, c, p, q, r. You will have to do something like this.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):

        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
        self.c = 1
        self.p = 1
        self.q = 1
        self.r = 1


    def some(self,a, b, c):

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def anyt(self, p, g, f):

        self.p = p
        self.g = g
        self.f = f


class B(A):

    def frog(self):

        self.some(self.a*2, self.b*2, self.c*2)


    def lion(self):

        self.anyt(self.p*3, self.g*3, self.f*3)

b = B()
b.frog()
print(b.c)
# Prints current value of c
```

This ensures the corresponding variable values change.

Comment: I think that's `self.some(self.a*2, self.b*2, self.c*2)`

Comment: a, b, and c are not being assigned to anything when some is called, so the corresponding variables won't actually change.

Comment: ... and it will work with any data type that supports multiplication, like a list `[1,2]*2`

Comment: @mkusz -I don't understand. `a` is assigned to `self.a`, and etc

Comment: @tdelaney True..it works with lists and tuples as well. Although that might not be what is needed in this case

Comment: For example: `self.a*2` will assign `8` to a in some. But `a` is not assigned to `self.a`. We still have `self.a = 4` inside some so the value of `self.a` won't change.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I think that you should remove the note. It puts a false limitation on the solution.

Comment: @mkusz - that's why `self.some(...)` is called to do whatever calculations and assignments it deems appropriate.

Comment: @tdelaney Maybe I am confused. Are we trying to change the values of `self.a, etc.` or something else.

Comment: @mkusz - `B.frog` changes the values of `self.a` etc by first pulling current values from the object, multiplying them, and then calling `self.some` which will set those values again. It seems a bit crazy in this toy example, but in the real world `self.some` may do other useful work like parameter validation or other calculations.

Comment: @tdelaney But it does not? `some(self, a, b, c)` never has a, b, or c assigned to `self.a, self.b, or self.c`.

Comment: @mkusz That is literally all that `A.some` (and by inheritance, `B.some`) does in this example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209109/discussion-between-tdelaney-and-mkusz).

Comment: There is a problem... `some(self, a, b, c)` should be assigning `self.a = a` etc... not `self.a = 4`.

Comment: I didn't see that as well...Brain fart. Code fixed

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution!! Now, how can I print the current value of c for example?? If I set the value of c = 1, then, according to the code it has to be c = 2 right? So I want to print out the new value, I am always using the print - Function but I do something wrong.. What is the proper execution of print in this case??

Comment: Ok thanks man, I thought there is another way to print out the value, without creating an instance, but i was wrong... The thing is, the code I posted here, its just a small version of the code I am working for. And second I am a totally beginner in python... Tomorrow I will post the real code to depict the issue properly. I hope can count on your support. bye!

Comment: Anytime. I'll keep an eye out for your post